# Activity destroyed while in onStop()

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, illegalstateexception, dismiss

I have this app which adds a dynamic fragment in an activity. The onStop looks like this

```
protected void onStop() {
    processingRequests = false;
    if (missedRequestDialogFragment != null) {
        missedRequestDialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss();
        missedRequestDialogFragment = null;
    }
    super.onStop();
}
```

However I get this error - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed while doing dismissAllowingStateLoss()

Stacktrace

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to stop activity 
  {com.example.android/com.example.MainActivity}:  
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:3581)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$3000(ActivityThread.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1478)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5590)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1280)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1096)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1549)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:654)
    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:625)
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissInternal(DialogFragment.java:199)
    at android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment.dismissAllowingStateLoss(DialogFragment.java:177)
    at com.pugmrks.app.android.MainActivity.onStop(MainActivity.java:918)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop(Instrumentation.java:1219)
    at android.app.Activity.performStop(Activity.java:5592)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSleeping(ActivityThread.java:3578)
    ... 10 more
```

Comment: try putting super.onStop() on the first line

Comment: @Sheychan That won't be it.  YOu don't need to call it first, and since onDestroy and onStop are called on the main thread there shouldn't be any possibility of being called at the same time (unless he manually calls one of those functions which he shouldn't).

Comment: No, I am not manually calling any of these functions. I though call finish() on activity at some places. Can it happen that two finish() calls on a activity creating such situations ?